# Does the additive closure of a set always have additivity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If I have some set X and define the set XC as the additive closure of X, is it possible that XC does not have additivity?

Additivity here is defined as follows: for every $a,b \in X$ ,$ a+b \in XC$

Today a TA told us that a set XC being defined as the additive closure of the set X does not imply that XC has additivity.

How is this possible?

**EDIT**

I only have an undergraduate degree in mathematics and so my understanding could be a bit course. However, I understand the following:

The additive closure XC of X is the smallest set containing X that is closed under addition. I perhaps did a poor job conveying that definition earlier. I hope this clears up some confusion.

EDIT 2

Definition of additive closure given in our text is: "The additive closure $Y^+$ of $Y$is the smallest set that contains Y that is additive: $Y^+ + Y^+ \subset Y^+$"

Comment: If we define $XC=\{a+b|a,b\in X\}$ then the most obvious counter-example  is $X=\{0,1\}$ then $XC=\{0,1,2\}$ which obviously isn't closed under addition (e.g. $2+1=3\notin XC$).

Comment: What's your definition of additive closure?

Comment: What do you mean by the additive closure of a *set*? Do you mean the additive closure of a subset of a group? If so, with the right definition this should always be closed under addition.

Comment: @TheRob Your $XC$ is not the additive closure of anything. The "additive closure" of $X$ would be the least set, in terms of set inclusion, that's closed under addition (i.e. "has additivity", an unpleasant phrase). Assuming the definition of "additive closure" just given, which is what anyone would expect it to mean, the TA was talking nonsense.

Comment: @BrianO I agree, I should clarify that is not what I think of as the additive closure, but with the usual definition of additive closure the additive closure has "additivity" by definition

Comment: @TheRob Ah ok. Right, there's either nothing to prove, or almost nothing. The latter, in case the definition is: additive closure of $X$ = intersection of all $Y \supseteq X$ that "have additivity" i.e. in human language, are closed under addition.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  -I have updated the post to expound upon my understanding of the definition of additive closure. Also, I will add the definition given in the text we use.

Comment: @TheRob - I have updated the post. I think the update will help clarify a few things.

Comment: What's the difference between "having additivity" and being closed under addition?

Comment: Oh, I see.  I don't see how that can be.  XC is closed under addition so for all $a, b \in XC$ by definition $a + b \in XC \subset  XCC$ so XC has additivity.  In fact as $XC \subset XC$ and XC is closed under addition, $XC = XCC$.

Comment: From what I understand, there is no difference. They are synonymous statements. I think this terminology issue arises because this is in an economics course.